# securing cleartext password string for psycopg2 connection?

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I read following relevant questions:

- [Can I use md5 authentication with psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782026/can-i-use-md5-authentication-with-psycopg2)
- [How to not show password in clear text when connecting to postgres via sqlalchemy, psycopg2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37131460/how-to-not-show-password-in-clear-text-when-connecting-to-postgres-via-sqlalchem)

but my question does differ a bit. I get from the answers, that the psycopg2 module uses md5 with salt and username to submit the password when connection with the connection of psycopg2.connect(). So for the actual connection, there is no further security needed as the psycopg2 module takes care of this. My question therefor is: How do i secure the the actual password-string? Is it sufficient to let it sit in cleartext in the source? I thought of also hash+salt and then save this in a password file separate from source. Or is it paranoid to think someone will gain db-access through the source?

Comment: you load it as an environment variable. So that instead of hard-coding your password in you do something like `os.getenv("my-db-password")`

Comment: isn't it clear-text in the terminal logs then?